# jquery Draggable DIV with slider inside

Tags: jquery, slider, rotation

Spent a few hours trying on Google and trying myself but no avail.

What I am doing is creating a DIV and making it draggable. And adding a slider inside it in order to rotate image. Creating DIV and making it draggeable and adding slider is all done on the fly. What I am doing basically is clicking on an arrow tool and it clones arrow tool inside a container and making it draggeable and adding a slider at the same time. Result would look something like this below.

```
<div class='draggable'>
  <img src='example.gif'>
  <div class='slider'></div>
</div>
```

The problem is the slider is draggable inside the DIV. How can I make DIV draggable but still have slider to work normally?

**New solution**

Yes, I did figure it out and decided to do another solution using SHIFT key to do rotation. I was able to use http://www.elated.com/articles/smooth-rotatable-images-css3-jquery/ solution and now I can simply rotate images using SHIFT key while moving mouse. Much simpler than slider and works great!

Comment: I found this tutorial with a different way of rotating images quite useful to read through...  http://www.elated.com/articles/smooth-rotatable-images-css3-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the jQuery UI Draggable and Slider components, this shouldn't be a problem - the two should not conflict with each other by default. However, you can still explicitly exclude the slider with the `cancel` option:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    cancel: '.slider'
});
```

See this jsfiddle for a simple example of this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/KMF2v/2

---

Assuming you're **not** using jQuery UI... well, in that case I suggest you go out and get it immediately, since writing your own slider and drag-'n-drop component is seriously hard work.

Still, the obvious solution would be to stop the event from bubbling down the DOM tree using [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$('.slider').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Hi Yi, thanks. I went to the link you sent (jsfiddle) but the slider is not working inside the DIV. I am on Linux Firefox 3.6. Thanks!

Comment: Works fine in Chrome. But not Firefox for some reason.

Comment: @Scott Doh! I know why the demo didn't work for you on Firefox. I had left an `console.log` in there which I forgot to take out. I'm so sorry... it should work now.

Comment: It would be cool to allow user to rotate while pressing SHIFT key instead of slider bar. I'll see if I can do it and if I do, I'll share code.